# Cannot boot on Arch Linux after modifying kernel parameters with GRUB

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, grub, arch-linux, grub2

Looking for a way to set my backlights on my laptop running Arch Linux (and Windows on a dual boot), I edited the `/etc/default/grub` file to change a kernel parameter. Here is what I changed:

```bash
# before edition
# GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="lsm=lockdown,yama,apparmor,bpf loglevel=3 quiet acpi_backlight=vendor"

# after edition
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="lsm=lockdown,yama,apparmor,bpf loglevel=3 quiet acpi_backlight=linux"
```

Then I regenerated the `grub.cfg` file with `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` and restarted my computer. I have never been able to boot on Arch since. I am still able to boot on Windows though.
From an Arch USB live session, I can still access my partitions. So, I first mounted them:

```bash
# my root is on the nvme0n1p5 partition and my home on nvme0n1p6 
mount /dev/nvme0n1p5 /mnt
mount /dev/nvme0n1p6 /mnt/home
```

Then I either did:

```bash
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
chroot /mnt
```

or directly

```bash
arch-chroot /mnt
```

and then I edited back my `/etc/default/grub` file to what it originally was (`acpi_backlight=vendor`). I even tried to remove completely the `acpi_backlight` parameter.
Then, I did `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` and got the following output:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-linux-lts
Found initrd image: /boot/amd-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-linux-lts.img
Found fallback initrd image(s) in /boot: amd-ucode.img initramfs-linux-lts.img
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
ERROR: mkdir /var/lock/dmraid
Adding boot menu for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

N.B: the `ERROR: mkdir /var/lock/dmraid` error only shows up when using `arch-chroot`, not when using `chroot`. Otherwise, the two outputs are similar.

I also tried to `grub-install --target=i386-pc /dev/nvme0n1` but without anymore success. Here is the output of this command:

```
Installing for i386=pc platform.
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition: embedding won't be possible.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible. GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists. However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged.
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

On my BIOS, I have the following booting path availables :

- `SYSTEM 256MB\EFI\arch` -> GRUB menu appears and display `error: unknown filesystem. Entering rescue mode...`, and then a `grub rescue>` prompt is given;
- `SYSTEM 256MB\EFI\Boot` -> boots on Windows.
- `SYSTEM 256MB\EFI\GRUB` -> GRUB menu briefly appears and then brings me back to the BIOS;
- `SYSTEM 256MB\EFI\Microsoft` -> also boots on Windows;

How can I make GRUB boot back on my Arch session please ?